# Can't bundle when deploying RoR app with passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, rubygems, passenger, bundler

I'm deploying an app to production using passenger and apache. I've deployed multiple apps on the same server without problems. However, for some reason I'm having problems with this app.

When I run **bundle** I get a lot of warnings I've never seen before:

```
WARNING:  #<ArgumentError: Illformed requirement ["#<YAML::Syck::DefaultKey:0x7fcbdc2ce610> 1.6.0"]>
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name = %q{bson_ext}
  s.version = "1.6.0"

  s.required_rubygems_version = Gem::Requirement.new(">= 0") if s.respond_to? :required_rubygems_version=
  s.authors = ["Mike Dirolf"]
  s.date = %q{2012-02-22}
  s.description = %q{C extensions to accelerate the Ruby BSON serialization. For more information about BSON, see http://bsonspec.org.  For information about MongoDB, see http://www.mongodb.org.}
  s.email = %q{mongodb-dev@googlegroups.com}
  s.extensions = ["ext/cbson/extconf.rb"]
  s.files = ["Rakefile", "bson_ext.gemspec", "ext/cbson/extconf.rb", "ext/cbson/bson_buffer.c", "ext/cbson/cbson.c", "ext/cbson/encoding_helpers.c", "ext/cbson/bson_buffer.h", "ext/cbson/encoding_helpers.h", "ext/cbson/version.h"]
  s.homepage = %q{http://www.mongodb.org}
  s.require_paths = ["ext"]
<SNIP>

<SNIP>
Using bson (1.6.0) 
Installing bson_ext (1.6.0) with native extensions 
Using bundler (1.0.22) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.2.0) 
Using execjs (1.3.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.6.5) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.2.2) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using geoip_city (0.2.0) 
Using jquery-rails (2.0.1) 
Using libv8 (3.3.10.4) 
Installing mongo (1.6.0) 
Using mongoid (2.4.6) 
Using rails (3.2.2) 
Using sass (3.1.15) 
Using sass-rails (3.2.4) 
Using therubyracer (0.9.10) 
Using uglifier (1.2.3) 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Although it appears as if my gems get bundled when I go to my app I get a passenger error.

[image: passenger error]

Anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Having the same problem with different configuration.
Started when i pushed a GemFile with the BSON 1.6.0 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently its a [bug](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/pull/93) with the ruby mongo driver 1.6.0 working with older RubyGems version. Its already fixed and will be in 1.6.1 (that should have been released a few days ago and i guess will be any day now).

In the meantime, patch your `GemFile` (hopefully you don't have all that 1.6.0 cherries...):

```
gem 'bson',  '< 1.6.0'
gem 'bson_ext', '< 1.6.0'
gem 'mongo',  '< 1.6.0'
```

HTH

Comment: I also get this error with bson_ext (1.9.1), bson 1.9.1 and mongo 1.9.1 using ruby 2.0.0, but no error with ruby 1.9.3. From the looks of other pages on google, it looks like rvm installs might be to blame. Try `rvm get head && rvm reinstall all`